# Customise QLPreviewController

Tags: ios, uidocumentinteraction, quicklook

I am using UIDocumentInteractionController and QLFramework to preview videos from the Documents folder of my application. I want to customise the the upload button of QLPreviewController just like WhatsApp show a custom UIMenuAction sheet.
Is WhatsApp creates their own Controller which looks like QLPreviewController then by using which class are they previewing videos? Can anybody suggest something??

Comment: No you can't you have to make your own class

Comment: QLPreviewController used only showing documents

Comment: So do you know how does whatsApp customise QLPreviewController?

Comment: @SunnyShah please suggest from class to preview videos. I have used MPMoviePlayerController also but I didn't like the UI of it.

Comment: You can customize the MPMoviePlayerController class. You can also use third party library.

Comment: look at this that might be help you : https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/almovieplayercontroller

Comment: thank you! I will have a look at it.

Comment: u better add screenshot to let people understand what u mean without downloading WhatsApp